# Powershell controlling MSWord: How to select the entire content and update?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am dealing with a whole load of Word documents that make heavy use of fields and cross-references (internally and between documents).
To update these and make everything consistent again after a change I have to open each file, select the entire file's content (equivalent of hitting Ctrl-A) and update all fields (the equivalent of hitting F9). And I have to do this **twice** for all files, so that also all inter-file cross-references are also updated properly.

Since this is a rather tedious and lengthy process I wanted to write me a little PowerShell-script that does that for me. The relevant function to update a file looks like this:

```
...
function UpdateDoc([object]$word, [object]$fileHandle) {
    Write-Host("Updating: '" + $fileHandle.Name + "' ('" + $fileHandle.FullName + "'):")
    # open the document:
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($fileHandle.FullName)
    # select the entire document:
    ???
    # update it:
    ???
    # then save it:
    $doc.Save
    $doc.Close
    Write-Host("'" + $fileHandle.Name + "' updated.")
}
...
```

But I am stuck on how to select the file's content and update it all, i.e. what has to go into this code instead of the two ???-markers to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$doc.Fields | %{$_.Update()}
```

That should update all the fields

Comment: It does! I had encountered the Update() before, but hadn't realized it's actually an UpdateAll() and that I don't need to select anything beforehand. Thanks!